# geoserver wps gs:clip error - "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it" hence "Failed to parse process inputs"

Tags: geoserver, wps

I'm working on GeoServer 2.10.1 , trying to work on `gs:clip` in wps.

I'm following this tutorial :

http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/wps/chaining_processes.html

and I'm using same input layers. When I execute the process i get the following error:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<ows:ExceptionReport version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://localhost:8081/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd"><ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode"><ows:ExceptionText>Failed to parse process inputs</ows:ExceptionText></ows:Exception></ows:ExceptionRepor
```

here is the screenshot of what i m doing......

[image]

the xml code from subprocess looks like below

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier/>
  <wps:DataInputs/>
  <wps:ResponseForm/>
</wps:Execute>`

Comment: did you solve this problem?